# Printer is presenting network problems, but responds to ping normally. How to isolate the error?

Tags: networking, printing, network-printer

Our office large format printer (which I'm told does not buffer) is presenting network issues. Whenever something is put on its queue, the printer will go offline, stop responding to pings, and will only come back up if restarted.

I have tried different cabling and a different port on the switch, none of which solved our problem. The printer will respond to ping normally when idle.

What other tests can I perform in order to isolate the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't changed any printer driver and the symptom is now there, it's most probably a trouble with the **DC formatter board**.

It's where the network connector is, and where the RAM is too. It's the *motherboard* for the printer.

You could try to do a firmware update, as it's stored into that part too.

To allow us to fully give you an idea please let us know the exact model and brand. Some model can be repaired by you and some other need a contractual to do so, so the model can be useful to your question.

*note: For a small so-ho printer I don't recommend to change that part, as if the damage is due to a power surge you could have to change other part after. (like the memory and the harddrive too if one is present)*

Comment: It's an Epson 7900 Stylus Pro.

Comment: @Zopiro as it's a big model please check the firmware first, and after like I told check for the repair via an epson certified technician. I don't know those model, as I was certified in the design-jet's hp serie more.

Comment: I've messed around with the printer settings via its web interface, and notice the ethernet port was set to use 100baseT Half Duplex, and changed it to Full Duplex. Would it make sense for that to be the source of our problems?

Comment: @Zopiro Yes. retry a printout to test it